# What slope do I need to prove a hypothesis?

Tags: experimental-design

I am conducting an experiment for school in which I am measuring people's heart rates as music plays at different tempos. My hypothesis is that as the tempo of the music increases, so will the subject's heart rate. After recording data from many subjects, I will use linear regression to find the overall function to represent my data.

What slope would I need on my function to prove my hypothesis correct?

Comment: As your hypothesis states: relating the tempo of music and the heart rate, the slope must be greater than zero.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs at SE-Cross validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I would worry less about the slope, and more about the p-value of the correlation.

Comment: It seems like you need to calculated a correlation ; It varies from 0 to 1.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Biology.SE. It seems like this question isn't quite about Biology, you seem to be asking a much more general statistics question. However, there isn't nearly enough here to motivate a migration to CrossValidated.SE. The general area you are looking for information in is called "power analysis" - I hope reading about power analysis can either help you directly or help you formulate a better question for CrossValidated.

Answer (score 1):

You will get a much more complete answer on a statistics forum, or by simply consulting some basic tutorials on linear regression.

But a little intuition should tell you that setting a cutoff on the value of the slope does not make sense. For instance, suppose you measured heart rate in beats per second instead of beats per minute. All the y-values would be 60x lower, your slope would be 60x lower, but intuitively, nothing should change about your interpretation.

When you calculate your linear regression, you'll be able to obtain a correlation coefficient and a p-value, which tell you how well your data fits the line and the probability of obtaining such a result if there was no relationship between the data. These will be based not on the slope, but rather on how well your data fit the line and the number of points you have (the more data you have, the more confident you can be of the effect).

But you will never *prove* your hypothesis. The best you'll be able to say is "if my hypothesis were false, the probability of obtaining the result I got is less than X%". The clearer your data, the smaller X will be.

You would also do well to consider sources of systemic bias, not just statistical power. For instance, could the music affect the accuracy of the measurement? Do you always gradually increase the tempo of the music, or do you randomize the order? Just some examples off the top of my head, I'm sure you can think of others more relevant to your setup.

Comment: Sorry, the word I meant to use was "accept" I asked this question on stats.stack exchange( https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/435803/265532) and posted some more details on it